# I can't composer install magento/extension-b2b

Tags: php, composer-php, magento2

Thank you for browsing.

I use "magento-ce-2.4.0-2020-07-24-11-08-21".

And I want to use [magento/extension-b2b](https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/b2b/).

But, I got this error message.

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find a matching version of package magento/extension-b2b. Check the package spelling, your version constr
  aint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).
```

I read https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html .
I made file "C:/Users/USER_NAME/AppData/Roaming/Composer/auth.json".

```
{
   "http-basic": {
      "repo.magento.com": {
         "username": "MY_PUBLIC_KEY",
         "password": "MY_PRIVATE_KEY"
      }
   }
}
```

Why I can't use magento/extension-b2b??

Comment: have you run Magento commands?

Comment: @MaryNfs
I didn't know "Magento Command". "Magento Command" is not listed in https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/b2b/.
What should I do?

Comment: by "Magento command" I mean commands like "bin/magento".
this link maybe help you https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14709#issuecomment-460243729

Comment: I read this document https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install-roadmap_cli.html .

Maybe I need a server for CLI install ?!?

Comment: Sounds like you should contact Magento's support for this

Comment: Sorry!! I use "Magento Open Source". I should used "Magento Commerce".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the extension because you haven't supplied all the arguments.
Based on https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/module-man/compman-checklist.html
and the details of the question you supplied, the reason you receive this exception is because you have failed to complete either of the listed..

1. Prerequisites for the package
2. the Module Manager checklist

*both of these lists of steps are documented in the link you supplied.

As you mentioned in the comments to your question you are required by the vendor to setup a server, as many of the prerequisite activities involve running operating system commands (CLi)

You can then either start the component manager, or upgrade the system.
This appears to be what the package is to be used for.

Comment: Sorry!! I use "Magento Open Source".
I should used "Magento Commerce".